# Почему Excel остается в менеджере задач, если его Workbooks (OleVariant) объявить не локально?

Tags: delphi, ole

Есть код заполнения шаблона Excel:

```
var
  Form2: TForm2;
  Excel_Templs: variant;

procedure TForm2.bVariant2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WBk : OleVariant;
  Sheet: variant;
begin
  Excel_Templs := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  WBk := Excel_Templs.Workbooks;
  WBk.Open('d:\Prog\_Example2\Книга1.xlsx');

  Sheet:= Excel_Templs.ActiveSheet;
  Sheet.Cells[1,3]:='23';

  Excel_Templs.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs('d:\test1.xlsx');
  WBk.Close;
  Excel_Templs.Quit;
  Excel_Templs:= UnAssigned;
end;
```

он работает – все отлично, после выполнения Excel удаляется из менеджера задач.
Но если переменную `WBk : OleVariant;`, объявить не в процедуре, а в «*private*», то файл «*d:\test1.xlsx*» создается, но *Excel* **ОСТАЕТСЯ** в менеджере задач и не удаляется. А удаляется из него только после закрытия приложения.

Почему это так, и как объявить переменную в “*private*” чтоб *Excel* удаляется из менеджера задач сразу после создания файла?

Comment: `WBk.Close;    WBk := Unassigned;` Пробовали?

Comment: @dr. F.I.N, да спасибо, помогло. Не хватало "*WBk := Unassigned*"